# Word to describe "semi-optimal" solutions

Tags: optimization, notation, article-writing

I have an algorithm (based on heuristics) that solves for a quantity $x$, producing a practically good result but not guaranteed to be optimal.

What adjective can I use to describe this "solution" $x$? "Suboptimal" has a negative connotation. I want to communicate that $x$ is good and useful although not the best possible.

Comment: Is there guaranteed an optimal solution that you're approximating? Or might there not be an optimal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a mathematical question. You could try "near optimal" or "satisficing".